# How do you align half the text inside an element?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a table in HTML5 and CSS. With one column of cells I want to align half the text to the left and half the text to the right.

The closest I've gotten is using `<p>` tags but the text is separated over 2 lines is it possible to split a single text with alignment?

```css
span.alignleft {
  text-align: left;
}

span.alignright {
  text-align: right;
}

p.alignleft {
  text-align: left;
}

p.alignright {
  text-align: right;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
  <title>Test Page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Link</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td><a href="#"><span class="alignleft">Some Text Align Left</span><span class="alignright">Some Text Align Right</span></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>B</td>
        <td><a href="#"><span class="alignleft">A</span><span class="alignright">B</span></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">
            <p class="alignleft">A</p>
            <p class="alignright">C</p>
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: use `display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;` on the `a` - see https://jsfiddle.net/kjv3n0c8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
span.alignleft {
  text-align: left;
  float:left;
}

span.alignright {
  text-align: right;float:right;
}

p.alignleft {
  text-align: left;
}

p.alignright {
  text-align: right;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
  <title>Test Page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Link</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td><a href="#"><span class="alignleft">Some Text Align Left</span><span class="alignright">Some Text Align Right</span></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>B</td>
        <td><a href="#"><span class="alignleft">A</span><span class="alignright">B</span></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">
            <span class="alignleft">A</span>
            <span class="alignright">C</span>
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

using float will do the job!

Answer (score 3):

```css
span.alignleft {
  text-align: left;
}

span.alignright {
  text-align: right;
}

.alignleft {
  text-align: left;
}

.alignright {
  text-align: right;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
  <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <title>Test Page</title>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th colspan="2">Link</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td colspan="2">
          <a href="#">
          <span class="alignleft">Some Text Align Left</span>
          <span class="alignright">Some Text Align Right</span>
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>B</td>
      <td colspan="2">
        <a href="#">
        <span class="alignleft">A</span>            
        <span class="alignright">B</span>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>C</td>
    <td class="alignleft"><a href="#">A </a></td>
   <td class="alignright"><a href="#">C </a></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</body>

</html>
```

Using rowspan and colspan you should resolve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```css
span.alignleft {
  text-align: left;
}

span.alignright {
  text-align: right;
}

p.alignleft {
  text-align: left;
}

p.alignright {
  text-align: right;
}
span.pull-right {
  float: right;
}
span.pull-left {
  float: left;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
  <title>Test Page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Link</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td><a href="#"><span class="alignleft">Some Text Align Left</span><span class="alignright">Some Text Align Right</span></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>B</td>
        <td><a href="#"><span class="alignleft">A</span><span class="alignright">B</span></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#">
            <span class="pull-left">A</span><span class="pull-right">C</span>
            
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

added class `parent` to `a` tag and added below css

```
.parent {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```css
span.alignleft {
  text-align: left;
}

span.alignright {
  text-align: right;
}

p.alignleft {
  text-align: left;
}

p.alignright {
  text-align: right;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.parent {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>

<head>
  <title>Test Page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Link</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td><a href="#"><span class="alignleft">Some Text Align Left</span><span class="alignright">Some Text Align Right</span></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>B</td>
        <td><a href="#"><span class="alignleft">A</span><span class="alignright">B</span></a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>
          <a href="#" class="parent">
            <span class="alignleft">A</span>
            <span class="alignright">C</span>
          </a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Flexbox to accomplish it. Notice the `.split-align` class is added to the anchor tag.

```css
.split-align {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Link</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>A</td>
      <td><a href="#" class="split-align"><span class="alignleft">Some Text Align Left</span><span class="alignright">Some Text Align Right</span></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>B</td>
      <td><a href="#" class="split-align"><span class="alignleft">A</span><span class="alignright">B</span></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>C</td>
      <td>
        <a href="#" class="split-align">
          <p class="alignleft">A</p>
          <p class="alignright">C</p>
        </a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```